# ajax multiple file upload alert after last file has finished

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I have set up a multiple file upload Form with jsp and ajax
 here is my code
jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=cp1251"
        pageEncoding="cp1251"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=cp1251">
<title>Загрузка файлов</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
<style>
    .td {
        valign: top
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function upload(){
       var x = document.getElementById("plan_upload");
       for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
          var file = x.files[i];
          var plan_type='${param.par_type}'
          var formdata = new FormData();
          formdata.append("plan_upload", file);
          var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
          ajax.cur_number=(i+1);
          ajax.total_number=x.files.length;
          ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandlerPlanUpload, false);
          ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandlerPlanUpload, false);
          ajax.onreadystatechange = function  (){   
                if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
                    var total_number = ajax.total_number;
                    var cur_number= ajax.cur_number;
                    if(cur_number==total_number){
                        alert('Загрузка файлов успешно завершена!');// upload successfull
                        window.opener.location.reload()
                        window.close();
                    }               
                }
           }  
          ajax.open("POST", "MultipleFileUpload?par_type="+plan_type);
          ajax.send(formdata);
        }
    }
function updateList (){
   var input = document.getElementById('plan_upload');
   var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
   output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
   for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
       output.innerHTML += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
   }
   output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
}
function errorHandlerPlanUpload(event){
   alert("Ошибка при загрузке файлов!"); //cancel
   window.opener.location.reload();
   window.close()
}
function abortHandlerPlanUpload(event){
   alert("Загрузка файлов была отменена!");//abort
   window.opener.location.reload();
   window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: white;">
  <form name="multiple_upload_form"   enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return false;" >
      <input  onchange="updateList()" accept=".xml,.osf,.zsf,.plax" id="plan_upload" name="plan_upload"  multiple type="file" required />
      <br/>Выбранные файлы:
    <div id="fileList"></div>
    <button id="testt" onclick="upload()" type="submit">Загрузить файлы</button>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

server side java

```
package com.ieml.servlets.plan;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;

    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*;

    import com.ieml.Global;
    import com.ieml.util.*;

    public class MultipleFileUploadServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(request, response);
        }   

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String path = com.ieml.Global.getUploadDirectory();
            Integer type= ServletUtilities.getIntParameter(request, "par_type");
            if(path == null)
            {
                ServletUtilities.forwardErrorPage(request, response, "Не указано место хранения файлов");           
                return;         
            }
            if(type==null)
            {

                ServletUtilities.forwardErrorPage(request, response, "Не указан тип плана");            
                return;

            }
            else
            {
                switch(type)
                {
                case 1:path+="/plans/incoming/"; break;
                case 2:path+="/plansMag/incoming/";break;
                case 3:path+="/plansSPO/incoming/";break;
                default:break;
                }
            }

            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(new ServletRequestContext(request));

            if (isMultipart) 
            {
                try
                {
                    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                    upload.setHeaderEncoding("UTF-8");
                    List<?> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                    Iterator<?> iter = items.iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        FileItem item = (FileItem)iter.next();                
                        if (!item.isFormField()) 
                        {
                            String fileName = item.getName();
                            if(!fileName.endsWith(".xml") &&!fileName.endsWith(".XML") &&
                                    !fileName.endsWith(".osf") && !fileName.endsWith(".OSF") &&
                                    !fileName.endsWith(".zsf") && !fileName.endsWith(".ZSF")&&
                                    !fileName.endsWith(".plax") && !fileName.endsWith(".PLAX")
                                    )
                            {
                                ServletUtilities.forwardErrorPage(request, response, "Поддерживаемые форматы  файлов: .xml, .osf, .zsf, .plax");
                                return;         
                            }

                            try (Connection conn = Global.getConnection()){

                                File f = new File(path,   fileName);
                                if(f.exists())
                                {
                                    boolean success=f.delete();
                                    if(!success)
                                    {
                                        try {
                                            System.err.println("Не могу удалить файл "+f.getCanonicalPath());
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                File uploadedFile = new File(path, fileName);
                                try
                                {
                                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    log(e.getMessage());
                                    ServletUtilities.forwardErrorPage(request, response, "Не могу записать файл.");
                                }
                            }                   

                            break;
                        }
                    }


                }
                catch(SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(FileUploadException fue){
                    fue.printStackTrace();
                    log(fue.getMessage());
                    ServletUtilities.forwardErrorPage(request, response, "Не могу принять файл.");              
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Due to the fact I have to use the old apache-commons file upload  I decided to make several ajax calls (one for each file), but only display the "upload successfull" message after the last file has finished uploading.
 For some reason sometimes browsers display more than one successfull
 upload alert instead of just one

It seem to happen more if I have many(15-20) files selected for upload. Server side upload directory is currently local folder. Any suggestions how to fix the issue with my onreadystatechange function?

I'm using chrome 49.0.2623.112 m and  firefox 52.1.1  on windows xp

UPD 
fore some reason  i always equals to the number of files

```
function upload(){
    var x = document.getElementById("plan_upload");
    var noOfFiles = x.files.length;
    var i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < noOfFiles; i++) 
    {
        var file = x.files[i];
        var plan_type='${param.par_type}'
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("plan_upload", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.cur_number=(i+1);
        ajax.total_number=x.files.length;
        ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandlerPlanUpload, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandlerPlanUpload, false);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function  ()
        {   
            if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
            {
                var total_number = ajax.total_number;
                var cur_number= ajax.cur_number;
                alert('i= '+i+' total files '+noOfFiles ) // i always equals  noOfFiles
                    if(i == noOfFiles-1){   //Check if last file
                        alert('Загрузка файлов успешно завершена!');// upload successfull
                        window.opener.location.reload()
                        window.close();
                    }

                }               
            }

        ajax.open("POST", "MultipleFileUpload?par_type="+plan_type);
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by my AJAX calls synchronous  by passing additional false argument to the open function of the XMLHttpRequest

```
function upload()
{
          var x = document.getElementById("plan_upload");
          var numOfFiles= x.files.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) 
          {
                var file = x.files[i];
                var plan_type='${param.par_type}'
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append("plan_upload", file);
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandlerPlanUpload, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandlerPlanUpload, false);
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function  ()
                {   
                    if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
                    {
                        if(i== numOfFiles-1)
                        {
                            alert('Загрузка файлов успешно завершена!');
                            window.opener.location.reload()
                            window.close();
                        }               
                    }
                }  
                ajax.open("POST", "MultipleFileUpload?par_type="+plan_type,false);
                ajax.send(formdata);
            }
}
```

Comment: Hope you're using the way how I explained. I'm wondering how adding additional `false` parameter will give you the expected resolution to your question. In your question it's clearly mentioned that you're getting n number of alerts based on n no of file uploads, and you wanted to show only alert message on successful upload of last file. Hence I checked the no of files and used condition to check if it's last file. However it's great to see you're relieved from your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, *you don't want to show alert on every file uploaded successfully. Instead you want to display only for last file.*

If I'm not wrong you've to check one if condition for the alert statement and check if it's last but nothing file.

```
function upload(){
    var x = document.getElementById("plan_upload");
    var noOfFiles = x.files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfFiles; i++) 
    {
        var file = x.files[i];
        var plan_type='${param.par_type}'
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("plan_upload", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.cur_number=(i+1);
        ajax.total_number=x.files.length;
        ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandlerPlanUpload, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandlerPlanUpload, false);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function  ()
        {   
            if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
            {
                var total_number = ajax.total_number;
                var cur_number= ajax.cur_number;
                if(cur_number==total_number)
                {
                    if(i == noOfFiles-1){   //Check if last file
                        alert('Загрузка файлов успешно завершена!');// upload successfull
                    }
                    window.opener.location.reload()
                    window.close();
                }               
            }
        }  
        ajax.open("POST", "MultipleFileUpload?par_type="+plan_type);
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
}
```

You can find small piece of [working code](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/njf6n5er/). Hope this helps.

Cheers..!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Vinoth Krishnan, but unfortunately I discovered that for some reason, i variable  always equals noOfFiles, therefore alert never fires( see the updated question)

Comment: I don't understand your point. There is no way `i` value always to be equal with `noOfFiles` unless you're uploading only one file. Because it taken from your file attribute length. Moreover if you're uploading one single file you'll get alert in first iteration itself.